# How to get value without using key from NSDictionary with the help of index?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
{
 id:1
 Vendors:
        {
          47:
             {
               items:{
                     }
               price:
                    {
                     this value I want
                    }
             }
          55:
            {
            }
```

- in above code I wouldn't know which vendor id it is at what index. So I cannot use valueForKey. Can I get price array for both ids like:

  arrayPrice:{
               {
                value1
               }
               {
                 value2
               }
             }

or is there any way to get key at index. So that I can use valueForKey:@"47"

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order, so indexes don't make sense.  Having said that your question doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268366/how-to-get-values-without-using-key-from-nsdictionary-nsmutabledictionary-in-iph check this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property of `NSDictionary` `allValues` but you can't maintain the sequence because `NSDictionary` index according to keys. You have to use `NSArray` if order matters for you.